# Symfony 4 + FOSRESTBUNDLE

Tags: api, symfony4, fosrestbundle

Good Evening. Please i'm using Symfony 4 to create an API. I've installed the FOSRESTBUNDLE but i don't see where i can modify the configuration file of this bundle. Please i'll like to set a configuration like 
fos_rest:
    view:
        #…
        view_response_listener: true

In Symfony 2, we do it in app/config/config.yml. Please Where will i do this in Symfony 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this article: https://codereviewvideos.com/course/beginners-guide-back-end-json-api-front-end-2018/video/setup-symfony-4-fosrestbundle

Check if you required this bundle with following command:

`composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle`

If you require it with this command but you still don't see file `config/packages/fos_rest.yaml` execute following command
`composer fix-recipes`

If you still don't see this config file, you can just copy-paste it from original recipe repository: https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/2.2/config/packages

Also check that this bundle is included in `config/bundles.php`

Comment: Thank You Nikita.
Your answer help me. I've execute the command composer fix-recipes, and i've create manually the fos_rest.yaml. Copie -paste and edit the orignal file from the link you gaves me. 
My problem has been solved.