# No fos_rest.yaml after installing FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony5

I just installed the FOSRestBundle to my Symfony 5 project using "composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle", however no fos_rest.yaml file is generated in my project. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Here is a post with the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343691/symfony-4-fosrestbundle

Answer (score -1):

When he asks if you want to execute recipes, say "yes".

Or try to run

```
composer fix-recipes
```

in your project directory.

Comment: i got this:  Command "fix-recipes" is not defined.